# Pass array from server side function using google script and html

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I have an html page that will be served to a google sheet app to be used as a UI. I would like to access an array from a server side function within the html file.  I am having trouble accessing a returned array. Here is what I have:

in html file:

```
<div id="id1">
   Starting 1
</div>

<div id= "id2">
   Starting 2
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML = "A change";
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
   function onSuccess(numUnread) {
    alert('You have ' + numUnread[0]
       + ' unread messages in your Gmail inbox.');
       document.getElementById("id2").innerHTML = numUnread[0];
}

 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
  .getPermits();
</script>
```

In code.gs:

```
function getPermits()
{
  var permits = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
     permits.push('Element ' + i);
  }

  return permits;
}
```

Right now I am just trying to figure out why the `div` with `id = "id2"`

does not get changed to the first element from the passed array. Instead, it is not changed. Also, there is no alert.  If I change the return of the gePermits() function to a string, both the div and the alert work as I would expect.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code runs well on my end. I can see both the alert and the `div` with `id = "id2"` get changed. See the code on my end here: https://script.google.com/macros/d/1gydz_8VoVZr2EXAogWqwvl5zQhTUPDzr2VUYnNN-0IeLxgz9P1hR43S0/edit?template=default

Answer (score 1):

Some types are not passed trough HTMLService, but you can always STRINGFY and PARSE it, try:

```
return JSON.stringify(permits);
```

and in the html:

```
function onSuccess(numUnread) {
  numUnread = JSON.parse(numUnread);
```

Comment: I can not even seem to pass a string. Or at least can't seem to access it on the html side.